# Finding control in a Panel within a panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a form in vb.net like so...

[image]

There is an outside panel named "pnlResults", Within that panel i have a further 10 panels. 
As shown there is label with the text as "name" in each of these panels.

I would like to access these labels through a loop however I have tried the following without success.

```
For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is Label Then
        If ctrl.Name.StartsWith("lblName") Then
            'Found the labels
        End If
    End If
Next
```

The names of all the labels I want to find start with "lblName", they are then identified individually buy a number from 1 to 10 following "lblname" i.e. "lblName1" etc all the way to 10

I believe this is due to the fact that a panel is its own container thus excluded from the loop of 'me.controls'. How do I get around this problem?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET or WebForms?

Comment: vb.net I did have it in the title but it was edited out t.t

Comment: VB.NET is just the language. Is it a web project, or a desktop project?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Desktop project for school

Comment: Thanks. It's a VB.NET Windows Forms project, BTW. But VB.NET is only the language. The important part is that it is Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Search the panel's control collection for panels only.

```
For Each pl As Panel In pnlResults.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)()
   For i As Integer = 1 To 10
    Dim lb As Label = pl.Controls("lblName" & i.ToString) 'is the label
   Next
Next
```

Comment: That will just return the names of all the panels within that panel. I will have to go down the hierarchy one again to do this?

Comment: I get an error 'Control' is not a member of 'system.Windows.Form.Panel' under pl.Control

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion

```
Private Sub findingAcontrol(ByRef panelx As Panel)
    For Each Control As Control In panelx.Controls
        If TypeOf Control Is Panel Then
            Me.findingAcontrol(Control)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Control.Name = "Button3" Then
            MessageBox.Show(Control.Text)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Add a button and call your function. For example:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    For Each Control As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf Control Is Panel Then
            Me.findingAcontrol(Control)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution. You are correct in thinking that since the inner panels are also containers that your code isn't finding controls within them.

This solution just simply goes one level and once it finds an inner panel, finds the label based on how many inner panels you've gone through.

**Update:** I had assumed this was a web application. Here is an example of something you could do with a windows form.

```
Dim i As New Integer
i = 0
For Each ctr As Control In pnlResults.Controls
    If TypeOf ctr Is Panel Then
        i += 1
        Dim lblName As New Label
        lblName = ctr.Controls.Find("lblName" + i.ToString(), False)(0)
        'Do something
    End If
Next
```

Leaving the code for a web application just in case:

```
Dim i As New Integer
i = 0
For Each ctr As Control In pnlResults.Controls
    If TypeOf ctr Is Panel Then
        i += 1
        Dim lblName As New Label
        lblName = ctr.FindControl("lblName" + i.ToString())
        'Do something
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You should document what FindControl is.  It's not a standard function.

Comment: @LarsTech, good catch! I had assumed this was a web application without verifying the tags.